# Karma keeps asking for more imports that have nothing to do with the tested component

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm testing my `DashboardComponent`, this is my `beforeEach` block:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        routing
      ],
      declarations: [
        DashboardComponent,
        Ellipsis,
        FavouritesComponent,
        FormatDuration,
        LoginComponent,
        SearchComponent
      ],
    });
    this.fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
  });
```

It already has a few imports that have nothing to do with the dashboard (like LoginComponent). But it keeps asking for more imports:

> Error: Component **** is not part of any NgModule or the module has
>   not been imported into your module.

Everything in `app.module.ts` is present so that's not the problem.

What causes this kind of behaviour and how can I resolve it?

Comment: What about adding the module these components are already a member of, to `imports: [...]`?

Comment: I'm not sure what u mean, like importing app.component? I tried it but didn't work, importing BrowserModule also didn't resolve anything.

Comment: I mean adding `MyFeatureModule` to `imports: [...]` (where `MyFeatureModule` is the module that contains "Component ****").

Comment: It doesn't belong to another module

Comment: How can it not belong to another module? Every component belongs to exactly one module, otherwise you can't use it in your Angular2 application.

Comment: So u mean the AppModule? If I import that and delete the other imports and declarations I get "No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document"

Comment: If you have all components assigned to `AppModule`, then yes, `AppModule`. Sounds fine. Have you tried to provide `APP_BASE_HREF`?

Comment: It is set in index.html (from the beginning). I can't immediately find another (recent) way?

Comment: Add `{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}` to `providers`

Comment: I have added that to providers in app.module. The error is now: Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router

Comment: Add `RouterTestingModule` to `imports`

Comment: Allright everything is working now, seems like alot has changed in the testing environment with the recent RC6. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, testing was changing a lot with almost each update but I think it's becoming stable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `AppModule` and `RouterTestingModule` to `imports` of the object you pass to `TestBed.configureTestingModule()`.

Not sure if you still need to add `{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}` when `RouterTestingModule` is imported.

See also this PR for the upcoming testing docs https://github.com/angular/angular.io/pull/2198/files

Comment: I have the same issue but adding the modules as suggested do not resolve it. Has something changed with 2.1.x?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, for the 2.1.x Angular release, you don't want to add AppModule instead I had to remove my separate routing module to get rid of this error and make my tests run successfully.

My test spec ended up looking like this:

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule, JsonpModule} from '@angular/http';

import {TypeaheadModule} from '../../node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/typeahead';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            RouterTestingModule,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule,
            JsonpModule,
            TypeaheadModule
        ],
        declarations: [AppComponent]
    }));

    it('should instantiate the AppComponent', () => {
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        expect(fixture.componentInstance instanceof AppComponent).toBe(true, 'should create AppComponent');
    });
});
```